# MySQL: how to avoid table lock in case of write?

Tags: mysql

I want to use MySQL database and one of the tables are supposed to be "heavy-write", a table that is written very frequently. Every write is supposed to be creation of a new row (and not updating a new row). 
I know that tables of SQL databases are locked for every write operation, which may cause performance issues. I want to know how to write to a table in MySQL database without locking the entire table and blocking it for an insertion of another row in-parallel.

Comment: I don't see how that would be possible. Insert implies index update, which implies table lock. But I suggest you see whether you really have a performance problem, and if so investigate solutions that are actually feasible, like reconsidering the number of indexes.

Comment: If insert implies index update, how does Cassandra allow write operations without locking the tables?

Comment: Cassandra and MySQL are two different systems with different approaches and goals. But you may be overestimating what parts of a table are actually locked when you read about "table locks" in MySQL. And what their effect is. So like user207421 suggested, I'd actually test if you run into performance problems. If you do, ask a precise question (tables, indexes, insertion speed, requirements, setup description). (It of course may turn out that MySQL cannot do what you need, and using cassandra (or a plain text file) might better fit to your requirements.)

Comment: why do you think that I overestimate the parts in table that are locked? As far as I know, it's impossible to insert two distinct rows in parallel to the same table. In a case that there are many write operations in a short period of time, it can cause performance issues. Am I wrong?

Comment: If the table is so write heavy - I believe, so soon you will end with having billions of records in the table. In that case, I would recommend you to go with list partitioning. Also, I believe, with partitioning you can take benefit of parallel writes